# How do I run exe based on Windows bit size?

Tags: windows

I have two .exe files, and I would like to create one program that will be able to run one of them based on the Windows bit size (ie, run `program1.exe` if 64-bit and run `program2.exe` if 32-bit). Does anyone know where I should start looking?

Comment: do you mean 32 or 64 bit?

Comment: @Keltari yes. I've edited the question to make that more clear

Comment: are these programs you wrote?

Comment: no. they are installers, and i would just like to run them based on which version of windows is installed

Answer (score 1):

You could use a simple windows Powershell script as your launcher.

Here's how you can tell your architechure from PS: 
http://depsharee.blogspot.com/2011/06/how-do-detect-operating-system.html

The idea is to check how many bytes long the IntPtr structure is. 4=> 32b, 8 => 64b.

If you really want an exe, in DotNet, you could use this check to determine if its 64b:

```
BOOL Is64BitWindows() {
 #if defined(_WIN64)
  return TRUE;  // 64-bit programs run only on Win64
 #elif defined(_WIN32)
  // 32-bit programs run on both 32-bit and 64-bit Windows
  // so must sniff
  BOOL f64 = FALSE;
  return IsWow64Process(GetCurrentProcess(), &f64) && f64;
 #else
  return FALSE; // Win64 does not support Win16
 #endif
}
```

more info here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/02/01/364563.aspx

Comment: Will this script be able to run on any version of Windows?

Comment: if it runs powershell, yes. or try the .net approach.

Comment: What script?  The code in the answer is c#

Comment: @Ramhound, any of the scripts in the link to blogspot. they cover several methods, including WMI queries. I think the IntPtr is the most graceful though.

Answer (score 0):

You can always check the `%programfiles(x86)%` environment variable.  If it's a Windows 64-bit machine it will return the path to "Program Files (x86)", if it's not 64-bit it won't be defined and  will just return "%programfiles(x86)%".

You can check this with a batch, PS, .Net, or whatever you'd like. :)